# JPA test class UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: jpa, junit

I'm running the example here:

https://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started

The example contains a test class:

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersistanceTest {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void initEmfAndEm() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("examplePersistenceUnit");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        em.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyTest() {
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error at this line :

emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("examplePersistenceUnit");

The error is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.loadResolverClasses(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:150)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader$CachingPersistenceProviderResolver.<init>(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:130)
    at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:88)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.getProviders(Persistence.java:75)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at entity.PersistanceTest.initEmfAndEm(PersistanceTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems you're executing the test with a Java version which is older than the version used to compile the classes (yours or the one of a library you're using).

Comment: True, the java version specified there is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and I think the problem will be fixed.